# how to set Setting Expires and Cache-Control: max-age headers for images only in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, caching, browser-cache

I have a website with files which are static like Jquery library, images and other JS files.

So, I wish to set expiry time for those resources specifically  so that those can be easily retrieved from users cache and without caching other static resources

can anybody suggest a way to do that in asp.net 3.5?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You should separate this static files in folder and configure it directly on IIS

Here's a example for IIS6:

http://www.websiteoptimization.com/secrets/advanced/9-7-content-expiration-IIS.html

Or via code you can implement an IHttpModule

```
public class CacheExpiresModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose() { }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        string url = context.Request.Url.ToString();

        if (url.Contains("/Static/"))
        {
            context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddYears(30));
            context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
        }
    }
}
```

and configure it on your web.config

Comment: Thank You,But is there a  way to do it from code behind or web.config.(Only for cacheing images images)

Comment: i think applying in the way suggested in link, will get all static resources cached.it doe not tell how to configure it for particular folder containg static resourecs

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage browser caching setting an expiration data through http headers. There is a brief explanation of this process from Google Developers / Page Speed Insight:

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching